# can't deploy Xamarin project in iPod Touch

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have some question about deploying project on Mac for iOS ( iPhone simulators or iPod touch real device, attached via usb to iMac).

About my problem, when I'm trying to deploy - I've got such messages in console at Xamarin Studio on iMac:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
 -installdev "/Users/Sladky/Projects/tst/tst/bin/iPhone/Debug/tst.app" "--devname=iPod touch
 (Oleg)" Please ensure your device is connected... Connected to: iPod touch (Oleg) Uploading
 application Application uploaded Installing application Installation failed: Your application
 failed code-signing checks. Check your certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle ids
 (error: 0xe8008015) error MT1006: Could not install the application
 '/Users/Sladky/Projects/tst/tst/bin/iPhone/Debug/tst.app' on the device 'iPod touch (Oleg)':
 Your application failed code-signing checks. Check your certificates, provisioning profiles,
 and bundle ids (error: 0xe8008015). The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

Comment: I'm quoting your error message here.. "Check your certificates, provisioning profiles,
 and bundle ids"

Comment: @0x7fffffff I have no experience with it. What must I do? I have only bought iMac and Xamarin Business license and installed Xamarin/XCode and other stuff

Comment: You'll need to go to the Apple developer website and login. From there you'll find the Provisioning Portal in which you'll find thorough instructions on how to configure your certificates/provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation on [Ad Hoc Deployment](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/ipa_support_for_ad_hoc_and_enterprise_deployment).  Deployment with Xamarin is essentially the same as when developing natively with Apple's tools.  You need to create a development account with Apple, register your device, create an Ad-Hoc distribution profile, etc